# Why when I create a Makefile with Notepad its saved .txt

Tags: c, linux, makefile, cygwin, notepad

When I create Makefile with Notepad it's saved with .txt How can I get rid of it ? also when I try to run the program on cygwin it says *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

P.S I am new to Makefile and Linux environments.

Comment: When saving to a new file in notepad, if you enclose the file name in double-quotes then it will not automatically add the `.txt` extension. That said, I think choosing another editor will benefit you in the long run - there are many free programming editors available. Nearly all of them are better than notepad in most ways.

Comment: Congrats you've chosen the incorrect answer. Windows ONLY adds `.txt` if you select "text file", if you select "all files" `(*.*)` then you can save it with any or no extension, contrary to what the other ones are saying. Btw. dual boot is also an option.

Comment: An additional detail: for this to work with "`All Files (*.*)`":  there must be at least one period in the filename or you still get the `.txt` extension. If you want an 'extensionless' name (common for makefiles), you need to type in a trailing period. The double-quote technique works without having to remember that detail. I still say using something other than notepad is a good idea. For most people the only advantage notepad has over other free editors is that it's already on every Windows box. Most other editors (even very basic ones) have many advantages over notepad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows will 'helpfully' add the `.txt` to any file that you create with notepad.  You have several options:

(1) just rename the file from makefile.txt to makefile and things should work

(2) use the -f command line argument with make, *i.e* `make -f makefile.txt` to get make to use the correct file.

(3) seeing that you have cygwin install use emacs, or vi, or gedit as your editor.

(4) consider using notepad++ (or something similar) if you must use windows.

(5) or (and this would be my default suggestion), ditch Windows and just install Linux.

---

At the bottom of the save dialog box, select

```
Save as type: All Files (*.*)
```

from the drop-down menu instead of the default

```
Save as type: Text Document (*.txt)
```

Then, you could use any extension that you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you select the correct file type (any) and not text file (*.txt) when saving the file (the latter adds .txt automatically if you don't do it). Btw you can also rename the file afterwards, but you have to show the file extensions in explorer to be able to change it.

Comment: Explorer hiding filename extensions: another irritating Windows behavior (at least it can be configured away).  I wonder if anyone really finds it helpful.

Comment: For unexperienced users it could be helpful, although I don't like it, same for the hidden files. There are a lot of things that could be improved, still I think it's quite comfortable to work with windows ;-) Of course not with notepad which doesn't have syntax-highlighting and other useful stuff.